# Which shuttle mission is this video from?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, identify-this-object, photography

At 12 minutes and 19 seconds into the NASA video [Space Shuttle Documentary (Narrated by William Shatner)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2fq8eC01HQ#t=12m19s), there’s a really neat video of a space shuttle lighting up the clouds from underneath and then disappearing into them.

What mission is this from? Is there a longer, higher-quality version of the source video available online from NASA?

3 second video: https://i.imgur.com/0OPPPBs.mp4

cued at `12:19`

Comment: your embedded imgur mp4 didn't show up correctly (looked like a broken link) so I've made the url explicit and then made your YouTube link visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's STS-134, the final mission of Endeavour.

There is a higher quality video here  but sadly it cuts away just as the vehicle enters the cloud deck.

Lots of cool ascent video here from that mission but a quick skim didn't show the cloud deck penetration.

There's a cool shot from the Shuttle Training Aircraft as the stack emerges from the top of the cloud deck.

[image]

(image source [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/flyout/multimedia/endeavour/11-05-16-2.html))

Comment: Thanks! I grabbed STS-130 footage off https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/multimedia/HD-index.html to get https://imgur.com/a/NpDwOVW, lighting up the sky at night

Comment: STS-109 featured a pretty cool cloud penetration event: [link](https://www.dvidshub.net/image/728252/sts-109-launch-view)